# How to put algorithm block in a minipage so that footnote displayed immediate after the block

Tags: footnotes, algorithms, minipage

as stated in title.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
% Need it for floating environment
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode} 
% Hide endif .etc
\usepackage{caption}
% Need it for \caption*
\usepackage{xspace}
% Fix macro spacing bug

\algrenewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\algrenewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\algrenewcommand{\algorithmicforall}{\textbf{for each}}
% \algrenewcommand instead of \renewcommand according to manual
\newcommand{\To}{\textbf{to}\xspace}
% Not stated in manual, \Return and \algorithmicreturn are defined, but no \algorithmicstate, why?
\newcommand{\Dosth}{\State \textbf{Do Something}\xspace}
% Note no space before \xspace
\newcommand{\Please}[1]{\State \textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\ForEach}{\ForAll}
% Fail to use \algorithmicforall, why?
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption*{\textbf{Algorithm:} \textsc{Depth First Search}} \label{alg:dfs1}

    \begin{algorithmic}[1]

        \Function{DFS}{$v$}
            \State $count \gets count + 1$
            \Please{mark} $v$ with $count$
            \Dosth with $v$
            \ForEach{vertex $w \in \mathcal{V}$ adjacent to $v$}
                \If{$w$ is marked with $0$} \Comment Only needed to exclude its parent.\footnotemark
                    \State \Call{DFS}{$w$}
                \EndIf
            \EndFor
            \State \Return
        \EndFunction

    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\footnotetext{No sibling is visited before the loop. Each sibling will be visited exactly once due to the nature of the loop.}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use the `H` placement specifier (provided by the `algorithm` package through the `float` package), thus allowing the inclusion of the `algorithm` environment inside a `minipage` (of course, `algorithm` won't float anymore); now, the standard `\footnote` command can be used to place the footnote.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
% Need it for floating environment
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode} 
% Hide endif .etc
\usepackage{caption}
% Need it for \caption*
\usepackage{xspace}
% Fix macro spacing bug

\algrenewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\algrenewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\algrenewcommand{\algorithmicforall}{\textbf{for each}}
% \algrenewcommand instead of \renewcommand according to manual
\newcommand{\To}{\textbf{to}\xspace}
% Not stated in manual, \Return and \algorithmicreturn are defined, but no \algorithmicstate, why?
\newcommand{\Dosth}{\State \textbf{Do Something}\xspace}
% Note no space before \xspace
\newcommand{\Please}[1]{\State \textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\ForEach}{\ForAll}
% Fail to use \algorithmicforall, why?
\begin{document}


\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption*{\textbf{Algorithm:} \textsc{Depth First Search}} \label{alg:dfs1}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]

        \Function{DFS}{$v$}
            \State $count \gets count + 1$
            \Please{mark} $v$ with $count$
            \Dosth with $v$
            \ForEach{vertex $w \in \mathcal{V}$ adjacent to $v$}
                \If{$w$ is marked with $0$} \Comment Only needed to exclude its parent.\footnote{No sibling is visited before the loop. Each sibling will be visited exactly once due to the nature of the loop.}
                    \State \Call{DFS}{$w$}
                \EndIf
            \EndFor
            \State \Return
        \EndFunction

    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: initially I explicitly loaded the `float` package to use the `H` specifier; this is not necessary, since `algorithm` internally uses `float`.

EDIT2: there's no need to use `\mpfootnotemark`; the standard `\footnote` command can be used inside the `minipage`.

Comment: very helpful